# Low light action with no flash and 300 lens

Tags: nikon

i need to take low light action pics, no flash in an auditorium at a distance. What settings do I use? Does having a flash mount help keep the flash from going off and take better pics? I can take flash pics after. Help! I have a lens that goes up to 200 and one that goes to 300mm. Which would be better?

Comment: There's not really enough detail to answer your question.  Determining whether or not you could shoot successfully would depend on available lighting, how fast your lenses are and the sensitivity of your camera body.

Answer (score 1):

At a large distance, a hot-shoe mounted flash won't help. To prevent the built-in flash to pop up, you have to select an apropriate program on your camera, either a "no-flash" scene mode or one of the advanced modes, consult your manual for details.

Whether you need a 200mm or 300mm lens depends, of course, on the actual distance and the scene you like to frame, we can't help you there without exact figures. That said, assuming you mean zoom lenses, the 300mm will surely give you more room to play with.

Otherwise, take the one with the lower minimum f-number, as you will want to shoot with as fast settings as possible (low f-number, high ISO) to get acceptable shutter speeds. A stabilized lens can also help to prevent shake, but you'll probably still want fast speeds to freeze subject motion.